# knp-snappy-bundle has private service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, knp-snappy

After update from Symfony 2.2 to Symfony 3.4 I get error

> The "knp_snappy.pdf" service or alias has been removed or inlined when
>   the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop
>   using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

config.yml

```
knp_snappy:
  pdf:
    enabled: true
    binary:  '%knp_snappy_pdf_binary%'
    options: []
```

in controller action:

```
$html = $this->renderView(
    'FsaBundle:Registration:registrationEmail.html.twig', ['data' => $data]
);

$pdf = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html);
...
```

How to make `knp_snappy.pdf` public?

Comment: What version of `KnpSnappyBundle` are you requiring in composer?

Comment: "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "1.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade `KnpSnappyBundle` to [1.5.2](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/blob/v1.5.2/Resources/config/pdf.xml): they've done it for you.
In case you're redefining the service (which should be useless), put the `public: true` in the definition.

Moreover, put `^1.5` as the version in `composer.json` in order to receive all compatible upgrades (`< 2`) of this bundle (and I would recommend to do so for every third party code that follows the [semantic versioning](https://semver.org)) during a `composer update`

If you would like to know more about composer and its constraints, checkout the [`^` (caret) documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-).

Comment: The newer version works. Thanks. [pull request](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/pull/177)